# Bash files or directories readable?

Tags: bash, shell

In the bash shell, how do I output files readable by ALL users (that is user, group and others).

I tried `find -readable`, but it outputs those that are readable by at least one of the users.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors that could affect how one user could read a file but basically you could search for files with +r attribute on the `others` group. And this is one way to do it using `find`:

```
find -perm -o=r
```

That would include both files and directories. To be specific to files, add `-type f``:

```
find -perm -o=r -type f
```

And it's probably the same as `-0004`:

```
find -perm -0004 -type f
```

Comment: Thanks, also, i want to output the files in long form, except when i pipe the find -perm ... command line into the ls -l command, it still displays those files that are not readable by the others group...not sure why

Comment: `ls` doesn't read target parameters from input. If you like you could store your output first on a variable then pass it to `ls` e.g. `readarray -t f < <(find -perm -o=r -type f); ls -l "${f[@]}"`. Note that you should be running bash 4.0+ to make it work.

Comment: I forgot you could use `xargs` as well: `find -perm -o=r -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l`. Or just use `find`'s exec: `find -perm -o=r -exec ls -l '{}' '+'`

Comment: Your snippet display files that not readable by all. Instead it displays all files.

Comment: @sputnick I tested it and it doesn't show files with modes like `0700`.

Comment: @user2672401 `xargs` collects input line by line and places those lines as one set of multiple arguments to the command specified with it in which case it is `ls`.

Comment: `find` has an `-ls` option which actually displays a long listing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for i in *; do
    [[ $(stat -c %A "$i") =~ (-rw.rw.rw.|drwxrwxrwx) ]] && echo "$i"
done
```

If you use [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4), you can do it recursively with :

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **; do
...
```

Comment: Neat! How about `$(stat -c "%a") & 666`

Comment: OP uses `find` as an example in the question, which implies that s/he wants a recursive solution. (Of course, assuming bash 4 you could just use globstar here.)